# nltk calc perplexity of bigram/trigram

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram, perplexity

I train bgram,trigram:

```
bgram = bigrams(sentences)
trigram = trigrams(sentences)
```

And want to calculate perplexity:

```
p = bgram.perplexity
```

But get an error:

> AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'perplexity'

How perplexity should be calculated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NLTK package to estimate the (unigram) perplexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266956/nltk-package-to-estimate-the-unigram-perplexity)

Comment: @RahulAgarwal no built-in nltk function?